# How to do a barplot with multiple colors?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

Im working with data of frequency and amplitude and I have a plot like this:
[image]

And as an output I have a file with all the values that form the curve, something like this:

['0.2', '1.2432', '0.8611', '1.7949', '0.2074', '1.1074', '0.8018', '1.5296', '0.215', '1.0072', '0.7446', '1.3624', '0.223', '1.0584', '0.7606'...]

I was able to the a plot like this:
[image]
But what I wanto to do is to plot this in one only bar with a variation of color related to the value of the y ax. LIke this:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10950-016-9564-x/figures/4

COuld anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw 1D heatmaps at different x-positions. The following approach uses `imshow` to create such heatmaps. It supposes the intensities for each time step are stored in a 2D array.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

num_steps = 20
num_intensities = 50
# first, create some random test data
data = np.random.randn(num_intensities, num_steps)
data = data.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
data -= data.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)
data = data / data.max(axis=1, keepdims=True) * 7

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('turbo')
norm = plt.Normalize(data.min(), data.max())
for step in range(num_steps):
    ax.imshow(data[:, step:step + 1], extent=[step - 0.3, step + 0.3, 0, 1],
              aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, num_steps - 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_xticks(range(num_steps))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: multiple 1D heatmaps]

PS: Here is how the code could be rewritten to work with multiple lists.  The data preparation is still using numpy arrays, as doing the same with lists would involve a huge amount of code. (Python would be unusable to work with numeric data without a library such as numpy.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

num_steps = 5
num_intensities = 50
# first, create some random test data
data = np.random.randn(num_intensities, num_steps)
data = data.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
data -= data.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)
data = data / data.max(axis=1, keepdims=True) * 7

list1 = data[0]
list2 = data[1]
list3 = data[2]
list4 = data[3]
list5 = data[4]
all_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
num_steps = len(all_lists)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('turbo')
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 7)
for step, list_i in enumerate(all_lists):
    ax.imshow(np.array(list_i).reshape(-1, 1), extent=[step - 0.3, step + 0.3, 0, 1],
              aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, num_steps - 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_xticks(range(num_steps))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are an angel

Comment: Im just not smart enough to apply this to my data, I have a list of values that I would like to be displayed as one bar. And I have other lists that would be the other bars in this chart. How can I do that?

Comment: Working with lists is really asking for the hard way.  I added some code to simulate how you could work with multiple lists.